# Write attribute to active record object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write an attribute to an active record object before returning it to the client.

```
user = User.find(18).profile
```

I'd then like to set `user[:random_attribute] = 'random_attribute'`

But I get the following error message

`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute random_attribute'):`

what's the best way to add random data to a record before returning it to the client?

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Does the User model have `random_attribute` column in the database? If no, you probably just need to add corresponding `attar_accessor` to the User class.

Comment: @dimuch it's not a column in the db, and that's on purpose. I'd just like to add arbitrary info along with the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need is a virtual attribute (there is quite a lot of information about ActiveRecord virtual attributes).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def random_attribute
    # ...
  end
end
```

If you want to assign the `random_attribute` value somewhere else in your code, you can do so by defining the corresponding getter and setter methods just like in any other Ruby class by using `attr_accessor`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :random_attribute
end

a = User.new
a.random_attribute = 42
a.random_attribute # => 42
```

Another way to define the getter and setter methods (in case you might need something more sophisticated):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def random_attribute(a)
    @random_attribute
  end

  def random_attribute=(a)
    @random_attribute = a
  end
end
```

Keep in mind though that during serialization, that attribute won't be included by default, so if you need this attribute in json, you might have to pass the corresponding arguments to the `to_json` method.

```
puts a.to_json(methods: [:random_attribute])
# => { ... "random_attribute":42}
```